# PyCharm: How to search in all files for something containing whitespace?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, search, pycharm

PyCharm's has two search features:

- Search everywhere (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>)
- Normal search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>).

Normal search only searches in the current file, but `Seach everywhere` can't search for literals containing whitespace.

Does PyCharm (version 2017.2.3) have this option?

E.g. in my case I know that *somewhere* in one of my many files I have a comment saying `this is a comment`, how do I find that (assuming the word `comment` isn't unique enough this use as sole keyword)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have version 2017.2.3, but just the next version (2017.2.4) and highers ones have no problems with literals containing whitespaces.

*PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4:*

[image]